# How to find the no. of nulls in every column in a polars dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, python-polars

In pandas, one can do:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"foo":[1,2,3, None], "bar":[4,None, None, 6]}
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
dict(df_pandas.isnull().sum())
```

[out]:

```
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

In polars it's possible to do the same by looping through the columns:

```
import polars as pl

d = {"foo":[1,2,3, None], "bar":[4,None, None, 6]}
df_polars = pl.from_dict(d)

{col:df_polars[col].is_null().sum() for col in df_polars.columns}
```

Looping through the columns in polars is particularly painful when using `LazyFrame`, then the `.collect()` has to be done in chunks to do the aggregation.

**Is there a way to find no. of nulls in every column in a polars dataframe without looping through each columns?**

Comment: Maybe `df_polars.collect().null_count()`? How does that work with LazyFrame?

Comment: Anyway to speed it up esp. when `df_polars.collect()` is not the best thing to do for large dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're not married to the output format the idiomatic way to do it is...

```
df.select(pl.all().is_null().sum())
```

However if you really like the dict output you can easily get it...

```
df.select(pl.all().is_null().sum()).to_dicts()[0]
```

The way this works is that inside the `select` we start with `pl.all()` which means all of the columns and then, much like in the pandas version, we apply `is_null` which would return True/False. From that we chain `sum` which turns the Trues into 1s and gives you the number of nulls in each column.

There's also the dedicated `null_count()` so you don't have to chain `is_null().sum()` thanks to @jqurious for that tip.

Comment: Cool! And the collect comes after the select. Awesome!

Comment: There is also a dedicated [`.null_count`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.null_count.html#polars.Expr.null_count)

Answer (score 0):

If you want row wise counts use this instead: `df.hstack(df.transpose().select(pl.all().is_null().sum()).transpose().rename({"column_0": "null_count"}))`

Comment: [`.sum_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.sum_horizontal.html) would be the idiomatic way to do it e.g. `df.with_columns(null_count = pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_null()))` - transpose is a costly operation and is best avoided if possible.